# How to extract a table from a *.dump file into a CSV

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, pg-restore

I have a *.dump file (postgresql dump) and I would like to output `my_table` to `my_table.csv`. Is there a better way to do this than `pg_restore -t my_table db.dump > my_table.txt` and then writing a script to create the CSV from the output?

Comment: For me the best way would be to restore the table to a database and then `COPY` the table to CSV.

Comment: Could you provide the steps to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output from `pg_restore --data-only -t my_table db.dump` basically *is* tab-separated headerless tabulated text with some comments and a few extra commands. A script to mangle it into csv with a tool like `perl` or `awk` would be pretty simple.

That said, personally I would:

- Restore the table to a temporary database created for the purpose. If the table depends on custom types, functions, sequences, etc you will need to restore them too.
- In `psql`, `\copy the_table TO 'some_file.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER ON)`

This way you can [control the representation of nulls and lots more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).